# Set Table Column With in Word with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

Im Building on a Powershell-Script which collects a set of Data to fill it into a word document.
Its the first time I work with Powershell in Combination with Word. There is very little Information about this, so if someone knows a good Source, i would appreciate this!

At the moment im Stuck with formatting my table. I want to edit the width of the Columns.

I tried the following things:

```
    $DocPath = "E:\Temp\Registry\EXCEL_ALLE\Version_AllFromExcel_Aktuell"
    $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $True
    $Document = $Word.Documents.Add($DocPath + "\IIS Application Pool.dotm")
    $Selection = $Word.Selection
    $Range = @($Selection.Paragraphs)[-1].Range

    $RowsCount = $hash.Count +1
    $ColumnCount = $Columns.Count
    $Table = $Selection.Tables.add(
    $Selection.Range,($RowsCount),2,

   [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDefaultTableBehavior]::wdWord9TableBehavior,


   $Table.cell($Row,1).PreferredWidthType = 1
   $Table.cell($Row,1).Width = 400
   $Table.Row(1,1).Width = 400
   $Table.Width = 400
   $Table.Column(1).Width = 400
```

But it doesnt work, the .cell command is only editing 1 cell(of course :()..
All the other combis i tried give me failure back like

> "The property 'Width' cannot be found on this object."

Or

> Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain
>   a method named 'Column'.

How can i set the With of a certain Column?

Comment: But.. doesn't the `wdAutoFitContent` you set on the table work then?

Comment: Theo again, thanks a lot ;) I think i have to delete this, i edited my post.. it want to stretch the table so it uses the whole page width. otherwise it looks not very good...

Comment: I see you have removed the line `[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior]::wdAutoFitContent`.. Did you try `wdAutoFitWindow`?

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what i want ! But is there no way to specify the exact with? Because like this both rows are quite huge, i would prefer to make the first column less wide and the second column should get the rest of the space..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for `Tables.Add` carefully you'll see that the last parameter, `AutoFitBehavior`, takes a member of the enum `WdAutoFitBehavior`. The three currently available values:

- wdAutoFitContent
- wdAutoFitFixed
- wdAutoFitWindow

You need the second, `wdAutoFitFixed`, in order to set exact column widths.

Note that your code uses `Table.Column(1)`- that should be: `Table.Columns(1)` - you're missing the `s` in Column**s**.

The `Column.Width` property expects the value to be in *Points*. If you want to specify centimeters or inches you need a conversion function of the `Word.Application` such as `CentimetersToPoints` or `InchesToPoints`. In your programming language it looks like like the following, for example.

```
$Table.Columns(1).Width = $Word.CentimetersToPoints(10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much cindy. By the way, do you talk about this documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.tables.add?view=word-pia

Comment: @LucaS That link is a possibility if you're comfortable with reading C#. Mostly, I use the VBA reference, however - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.tables.add - and it's probably closer in syntax to what Powershell *appears* to use. Note that the site is incredibly slow, probably because they prefer people work with the new JS APIs (which displays much more quickly) and try to discourage use of the COM object models... The other option is to use the VBA Editor in the Word application (Alt+F11) with the Object Browser (F2), click on the term, then go to the VBA Help topic.